# Google-Maps-for-Rails - Access user location in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am using Gmaps4rails which I like very much and it is working fine to place markers on a map.

Controller:

```
@advertisements = Advertisement.order(sort_column  + " " + sort_direction)
@json = Advertisement.all.to_gmaps4rails
```

I am detecting the user location and centering the map accordingly. This works fine.

```
<%= gmaps("map_options" => { "detect_location" => true , "center_on_user" => true, "zoom" => 13},"markers" => { "data" => @json }) %>
```

What I would like to do is to have a heading to the map like "Advertisements close to XXX" and then print the user location. However how can I access this in the view when the page is first loaded?

I have been trying to do stuff like:

```
alert(Gmaps.map.userLocation);
```

As mentioned here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Javascript-goodies
but this just returns null.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.